# PHP SOA login function

Tags: php, xml, json

I was trying to build a php application which should be in form of service oriented.So I"m trying to build a login page , when I pass the user name & password with the URL I should get a confirmation  with user details.I don't know what to do.So please help me!

Comment: I made login script in MVC,but this login function can't use outside the application.If I need to check login I'm intented to send a url like http://www.exaple.com/login?username=username&&password=password

Comment: you should NEVER send your password in the querystring.

Answer (score 0):

So for this type of login form, you should look into [.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) from jQuery, if you wish to use that.

Comment: Hi Jan,If I use jquery is it become Service oriented?